# QGIS Raster Calculator Generates Unexpected Results

Tags: qgis, raster

I want to perform a simple calculation on a raster (.tif) file in QGIS3.22, but it is generating unexpected values in the output. The image below shows the "input" layer to the calculation.
[image: Input raster layer.]

I then use the "raster calculator" and enter the following options:
[image]

Clicking OK yields the following "temporary" layer:
[image]

I've tried various methods without success. I also used GDAL (Python) to read the `.tif` file and edit it, but this is not a feasible long term solution. All the `.tif` files have a single band and when I query the "input" layer in the regions of study, there is "no data" under these points. As a result I think that the raster calculator is incorrectly interacting with the missing data leading to "memory overflow". I've encountered similar looking numbers when examining unallocated memory with the `C` programming language in the past (unrelated and integers instead of floats).

Comment: Have you considered using Grass instead of GDAL ?

Comment: It looks like NoData, as you expected, are being calculated also. Check that the NoData is correctly defined; I've had better success when converting GeoTIFF to ERDAS IMG format  as the TIFF specification has been touched by lots of interested parties and has become a little sloppy.

Comment: @BERA, I performed this action, but it did not solve the issue. The minimum is indeed `-3.4e+38`, which is a pain. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I've now also tried your suggestion of using the `ERDAS IMG` format. I'm going to make a new question about this because the output was even more strange.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, your approach using `ERDAS IMG` has solved the problem. Thank you. I'm not a hundred percent sure how stack exchange works but if you want to post an answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, adding a raster offset heights to a DTM, to obtain a sort of DSM. The two raster are GeoTIFF and have the same extension and pixel resolution, both Float64 data type.

The result is a GeoTIFF that have that strange 'no data' values.

Converting the two raster data in ERDAS Imagine format didn't fixed the issue, moreover I obtained a raster with totally wrong values for the heights.

The odd thing is that adding the very same two raster in ArcMap, using raster calculator, I obtain a suitable raster data, with minimum and maximum values compatible with the added heights.

I think this odd behaviour of QGIS with raster calculator deserves a serious fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).