# Raster calculator in QGIS returns 8.367e-11 instead of zero

Tags: raster-calculator, raster-conversion

I've a raster layer with nine classes, values 1 to 0.05. In the processing toolbox-raster analysis-raster calculator of QGIS, version 3.28.9, I've used the formula:

```
0.00872-(raster layer*0.00872)
```

Now those original raster pixels with the value of 1 are expected to be zero. However, it returns 8.367e-11 for those pixels, other values being as expected. When viewed in the properties-symbology, the value of 8.367e-11 is zero, but using the identifying feature, 8.367e-11 is shown. I've also changed the label to zero, which was 8.367e-11, but no change.

Comment: It sounds like a dodgy NoData value, there was a similar question yesterday. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464314/qgis-raster-calculator-generates-unexpected-results

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the issue and your quick reply. GDAL raster calculator solves my case.

Comment: More likely to be floating point precision error.